# Mysql Group by Year and Count field

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a table like this:

```
|  id  |  name  |  register_date  |  gender  |

|1     |John    |2011-02-02       |man       |
|2     |Jane    |2011-02-02       |woman     |
|3     |Jihn    |2012-04-04       |man       |
|4     |Jeni    |2012-02-02       |woman     |
|5     |Joni    |2012-02-02       |woman     |
```

How is the query to create this result from that table above?

```
|  RegisterYear  |  man  |  woman  |

|2011            |   1   |    1    |
|2012            |   1   |    2    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the year and sum each gender

```
select year(register_date) as registeryear,
       sum(gender = 'man') as man,
       sum(gender = 'woman') as woman       
from your_table
group by registeryear
```

Comment: @hanky: Thanks I missed that comma

Comment: Thank you very much Juergen ! thats working
and thank you for the correction Hanky :D

Comment: please remove comma (,) from third line in your query after woman

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT YEAR(register_date) as RegisterYear,
       SUM(gender = 'man') as man,
       SUM(gender = 'woman') as woman
from register 
group by RegisterYear;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92b0e/7)</kbd>

Output:

```
REGISTERYEAR    MAN     WOMAN
===================================
2011            1       1
2012            1       2
```